Ejbca CMP Initialization Request (ir) fails when -trusted option is given
It all works fine when the -srvcert option is given. But when I give the -trusted option, I get the following output from the cmp client:
CMP info: sending IR
CMP info: received IP
CMP info: sending CERTCONF
CMP info: received PKICONF
CMP error: missing protection

And this error from ejbca docker log:
2024-09-28 14:29:39 INFO [org.ejbca.ui.web.protocol.CmpServlet] (default task-5) CMP message received from: 172.20.0.1, for CMP alias: 3gpp
...some info msg in between...
ERROR [org.ejbca.core.protocol.cmp.ConfirmationMessageHandler] (default task-5) Exception during CMP response signing: No alias found for key purpose 1: com.keyfactor.util.keys.token.CryptoTokenOfflineException: No alias found for key purpose 1

Does anyone know what’s causing this behavior?
My CA-setup is the management-ca as root and a sub-ca to be handling the cmp server. (sub issued my management ca)
I tried:

Recreating the cryptotoken
Made sure the token is activated
Made sure both CAs are activated
Made sure the token has a SignKey
Made sure the SignKey is correctly mapped to the CA
Restarting the docker container
Changing the "cmp response configuration" to various options
Changing "certificate confirmation"
Changing the CA that is to be used to issue the certificate (management / sub)
Made sure the correct trustanchor is given with the -trusted option (I would otherwise get a different error)


You should enable debug logging and analyze the part "...some info msg in between..." with that enabled.
